# Form values are not overwritten when changed - they are stuck at their default values

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have the following `view`:

```py
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    
    instance = my_model(user=request.user)
    form = my_model_form(request.POST,instance = instance)   
 
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)

            #Field1 and field2 is already in the form (its the input)
            # Do some back-end operations to get values for the remaining fields
            df = some_util_function()
            form.field3 = df["field3"]
            form.field4 = df["field4"]
            form.field5= df["field5"]
            form.save()

            return redirect("my_html")
    else:
        form = my_model_form()

    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, "discounttracker/my_html.html",context=context)
```

and the problem is that `field3,field4,field5` are not changed. I have even tried to hard-code them to `1000, 2000,3000` (they are `FloatField(default=0)`) but they remain at their default value when written to the DB.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the attributes of the *form*, not of the *instance* wrapped in the form. You should alter this to:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    instance = my_model(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = my_model_form(request.POST, instance = instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Field1 and field2 is already in the form (its the input)
            # Do some back-end operations to get values for the remaining fields
            df = some_util_function()
            #       ↓ the instance of the form
            form.instance.field3 = df['field3']
            form.instance.field4 = df['field4']
            form.instance.field5 = df['field5']
            form.save()

            return redirect("my_html")
    else:
        form = my_model_form()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'discounttracker/my_html.html', context=context)
```

Comment: That works like a charm! Do you by any chance have the documentation for it? I'm fairly new to Django

Comment: @CutePoison: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset (while it is on a `ModelFormSet`, the idea is the same).